# OS X SSH behind proxy with username and password possible?

Tags: linux, macos, proxy, ssh

Is there a way to SSH into a server (my home computer) from behind a proxy that has a username and password? I read about corkscrew, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way.
Maybe some nc tricks.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason your behind a proxy that blocks outbound traffic to port 22, you might try to change to a different port on your ssh server.

-Tony